# Hibernate Criteria Subquerys

Tags: hibernate, criteria, exists, subquery

Can someone please help me to write the follow query in criteria? I don't know how to make that subselect.

```
select * from modulo m  
left outer join grupomodulo gm on m.grupomodulo_id = gm.Id  
left outer join grupousuariomodulos gum on gum.modulo_id = m.Id  
left outer join grupousuario gu on gum.grupousuario_id = gu.Id  
where exists  
(  
select Id from  
(  
select distinct(sm.Id), sm.nome from modulo sm  
left outer join grupomodulo sgm on sm.grupomodulo_id = sgm.Id  
left outer join grupousuariomodulos sgum on sgum.modulo_id = sm.Id  
left outer join grupousuario sgu on sgum.grupousuario_id = sgu.Id  
order by sm.Nome  
limit 10 offset 10  
)  
as subquery  
where Id = m.Id  
)  
order by m.Nome
```

Answer (score 0):

The subselect would need to be done via [Subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Subqueries.html).

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Modulo.class, "modulo");
criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(subCriteria));
```

Note that this is without the `order by` and `limit`. I would first see whether this works, then look into the ordering and limit. Without details, I am assuming the `joins` are already accomplished in your `Modulo` Domain class.